# Horizontal scrollbar disappears

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with approximately 20 columns, where the first column is set to always be visible, allowing the horizontal scroll to show the remaining columns.

I have just set the first column width to be based on the maximum text value contained within it:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

However, now the column sizes the entire width of my window and the horizontal scroll bar has disappeared, preventing me from seeing the remaining columns.

I'd like to size column0 width to show all text in column0, but still have the horizontal scroll to see the remaining columns. Is this possible or is there a conflict?

Comment: What do you have the property set to for the datagridview's columns autosize mode? I know for column[0] you have all cells, but you probably need to make sure the default for all columns is set to Fill. I'm afk so I can't test.

Comment: If the width of frozen column is greater than or equals to width of grid, horizontal scrollbar is useless because the column is frozen and should be shown and occupied all width of grid, so the grid doesn't show it.

Comment: I removed the answer but I'll keep the comment here for future readers. I believe when someone helps you to solve your problem, not answering comments is somehow rude.